# How to detect that document loading has started through javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, load, document-ready

I want to detect when the document has just started to load, so that I can make an ajax call right away...which will determine whether I need to navigate to another page or not. I don't want to wait for the entire page to load before firing the ajax, and then, possibly navigating away from this page on the basis of the result of this ajax request.

Comment: instead of making an ajax call as soon as a page loads, why aren't you just checking these conditions on the server before the page loads in the first place? seems like quite a waste of bandwidth.

Comment: Its to deal with the back button.. the first time I will do the checking whether the user is logged in at the server side.. but when the user has navigated away from the page, and then comes back.. the only way I can tell whether the page is to be displayed is through an ajax call asking the server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just put code in the `head` of the document, no?
or at the start of the body.

Comment: Agreed, the best option, is to simply make the call right away...  Though I question even making such a call in the first place on the client, and not just doing it on the server.

Comment: Its to deal with the back button.. the first time I will do the checking whether the user is logged in at the server side.. but when the user has navigated away from the page, and then comes back.. the only way I can tell whether the page is to be displayed is through an ajax call asking the server

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  function pageLoad() { 
    // Initialization code here, meant to run once. 
  } 
</script>
```